# data driven from yml file passed through the example section is not working in karate

Tags: karate

Working scenario:
Feature: Test feature

Scenario Outline: Test scenario

```
Given url 'some url'
Given def nameList = read('names.yml')

And print <name>
Examples:
  | name                |
  | nameList.firstName  |
  | nameList.lastName   |
  | nameList.middleName |
```

each run the name is printed properly

Not working scenario:
Feature: Test feature

Scenario Outline: Test scenario

```
Given url 'some url'
Given def nameList = read('names.yml')
And path 'api/<name>'
When method get
And print <name>

Examples:
  | name                |
  | nameList.firstName  |
  | nameList.lastName   |
  | nameList.middleName |
```

instead of value, its sending as api/nameList.firstName,api/nameList.lastName,nameList.middleName

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make this change:

```
And path 'api', <name>
```

Comment: Works fine... Thanks Thomas